# How to create the wrapper cards shown in Angular Material examples

Tags: angular-material

Each material component example is wrapped in a card e.g: [image]

How can i replicate this wrapper? Is the style is custom made for the site is or is easy reproducible using Angular Material?

Comment: custom made.. :) but you can get basic idea from dialog box ... with content and actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular material website is [open source](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io), so you can have a look at it for yourself.

Specifically, the component you are looking for is [this one](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/shared/example-viewer/example-viewer.html).